# Non exact differential equation - integration factor problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Can you help me with this one?

[image]

I have checked it and it is non-exact:

$$d/dy(-ycos(ln(y/x))=-cos(ln(y/x))+sin(ln(y/x))$$
$$d/dx(x)=1$$
So, I should find integrating factor with solving this:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$xdy-y \cos \left(\log \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)dx=0$$
The differential equation is homogeneous. Substitute $y=t x \implies y'=t'x+t$:
$$t'x+t-t \cos \left(\log t\right)=0$$
It's separable:
$$xt'=t(\cos \left(\log t\right)-1)$$
$$\int \dfrac {d \log t}{\cos \left(\log t\right)-1}=\int \dfrac {dx}{x}$$

Comment: Thank you, it really helped)

Comment: You're welcome @jane

Answer (score 1):

$$x y'-y \cos \left(\log \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)=0$$

Let $y=x e^z$ to get
$$x z'-\cos (z)+1=0$$ Now, switch variables
$$\frac x{x'}-\cos(z)+1=0\implies \frac {x'}x=\frac 1 {\cos(z)-1}$$ which looks workable.